# Should WebSockets be closed?

Tags: haskell, websocket

I was looking at some WebSocket library for Haskell, namely [Wuss](https://github.com/tfausak/wuss) and found something that might render it unusable.

The latest commit ([04ab5d3f72](https://github.com/tfausak/wuss/tree/04ab5d3f725d61fa15d8ecccfeaa6518713aa3aa)), uses [`Control.Exception.Bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket) and **always closes** the connection.

[Wuss.hs#L163](https://github.com/tfausak/wuss/blob/04ab5d3f725d61fa15d8ecccfeaa6518713aa3aa/Wuss.hs#L163)

```
runSecureClientWithConfig host port path config options headers app = do
    context <- Connection.initConnectionContext
    Exception.bracket
        (Connection.connectTo context (connectionParams host port))
        Connection.connectionClose     -- <-- This line closes the connection
        (\connection -> do
            stream <-
                Stream.makeStream (reader config connection) (writer connection)
WebSockets.runClientWithStream stream host path options headers app)
```

If I'm not mistaking, shouldn't this function keep the connection open as it's a WebSocket (or close it only if something errored)?

I would be surpirsed for a library with recent commits (2017) to have such a bug and I'm no expert in Haskell nor in WebSockets so I might just be missing something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of this function is that it runs `app`, and once `app` terminates the resources it used are recovered.

Typically `app` will be a long-running thing which listens at the port for connections and does the appropriate thing when one arrives. So closing the port and recovering the resources is the Right Thing. The [previous version](https://github.com/tfausak/wuss/commit/408d551debf74bf99e4df257522cf25ef82fd6d8) didn't do this, leading to a resource leak.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the word "thing" too much.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.
Some old sample code on the Internet was using this function to merely fork off workers and return (causing the socket to close for newer Wuss versions). I guess the sample was using this function in the wrong way to start with.

Comment: @DaisukeShimamoto, yes I think so. It should be "fork $ runSecureClientWithConfig ..." rather than "runSecureClientWithConfig ... $ fork ..."